# Query is still running

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sysdba

We have killed a specific query but still is running in background. How can we kill permanently. It's urgent.

Regards
Debajit

Comment: It's running not more! You killed the wrong spid or it's merely being rolled back, what for an intense UP/DEL/INS long running one can take a while.

Answer (score 2):

First execute the below command:

> sp_who2 'active'

Check values under CPUTime and DiskIO. Note the SPID of process having large value comparatively.

After that execute the below command with SPID, which you got from above command:

> kill {SPID value}

Comment: Just a few notes to add, there is a chance they will see it stuck in killed/rollback after this occurs. [Shanky_621](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c35b16c4-23f3-4aa6-bb18-78d899d50a60/killedrollback-opretion-is-get-stuck-from-last-24-hours?forum=sqlgetstarted) had the resolution for that, there are other resources online that suggest similar fixes if that occurs.

Comment: @Debajit, could you please tell us after killing Session did you see any error message or result? for an Example (SPID 57: transaction rollback in progress. Estimated rollback completion: 80%. Estimated time remaining: 10 seconds)